# exporting datagridview data to excel in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel, excel-2013

I need to export the filtered data on my datagridview to excel, any idea how I could do that?

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate, 
My MS Excel is Excel 2013,
I am also using MySQL Workbench as my database

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a tutorial on how to export datagridview data to an excel file. The Excel file is used in this tutorial is Excel 2007 though. I am not sure if it works on Excel 2013. Also the tutorial uses an Access table to populate the datagridview. Give it a try and hopefully it will help you.

Link:

[Export DataGridView Data to an Excel Sheet in Visual Basic .NET](http://www.visual-basic-tutorials.com/export-datagridview-to-excel-in-visual-basic.html)

Answer (score 0):

If your data from DataGridView is already filtered, see the VB.NET code sample from this link:

[Export DataGridView to Excel in VB.NET](http://www.easyxls.com/manual/FAQ/export-datagridview-to-excel.html)

If you want to export data directly from MySQL database, see the VB.NET code sample from this link:

[Export DataSet to Excel in VB.NET](http://www.easyxls.com/manual/basics/export-dataset-to-excel.html)

It uses an [Excel library for VB.NET](http://www.easyxls.com/net-excel-library) that supports all Excel 2013 file formats.